# Count all products (with qty > 0) group by all brands. But get aslo count zero for brand which have 0 products

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have table:

brands

```
brand_id  name
1         Apple
2         Sony
3         Nokia
4         HTC
```

products

```
id  brand_id qty
1   1        3
2   3        0
4   1        1
2   2        1
```

I need to get (all brands from brands table and products.qty > 0)

```
brand_id   count_products
1          2
2          1
3          0
4          0
```

I tried

```
SELECT `p`.`brand_id` AS `id`,
       COUNT(p.brand_id) AS COUNT
FROM `products` AS `p`
WHERE AND `p`.`qty` > 0
GROUP BY `p`.`brand_id`
```

But I get results only for brands that available in products_table.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.brand_id,
       COUNT(p.brand_id)
FROM brands b
LEFT JOIN products p ON b.brand_id = p.brand_id
                    AND p.qty > 0
GROUP BY b.brand_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only brands that exists in products table:

> ```
> select distinct p.brand_id,
>        (select count(*)
>         from   products 
>         where  brand_id = p.brand_id
>         and    qty > 0) as cnt
> from   products p;
> ```
>
> ```
> brand_id | cnt
> -------: | --:
>        1 |   2
>        3 |   0
>        2 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b489a0dc236cc9181fa479e32eab80d8)*